# Efficient way to update column value for subset of rows on Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

When using Pandas to update the value of a column for specif subset of rows, what is the best way to do it?

Easy example:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : pd.Series(['Alex', 'John', 'Christopher', 'Dwayne']),
                   'value' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.])})
```

Objective: update the `value` column based on names length and the initial value of the value column itself.

The following line achieves the objective:

```
df.value[df.name.str.len() == 4 ] = df.value[df.name.str.len() == 4] * 1000
```

However, this line filters the whole data frame two times, both in LHS and RHS. I assume is not the most efficient way. And it does not do it 'in place'.

Basically I'm looking for the pandas equivalent to R data.table ':=' operator:

```
df[nchar(name) == 4, value := value*1000]
```

And for other kind of operations such:

```
df[nchar(name) == 4, value := paste0("short_", as.character(value))]
```

Environment: `Python 3.6` `Pandas 0.22`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be what you require:

```
 df.loc[df.name.str.len() == 4, 'value'] *= 1000

 df.loc[df.name.str.len() == 4, 'value'] = 'short_' + df['value'].astype(str)
```

Comment: Thanks @jp_data_analysis. That worked perfectly. Would you care to explain or point to why `df['value']` on RHS is filtered by the rows subset? Is using `.loc` which does the trick?

Answer (score 8):

You need [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with `*=`:

```
df.loc[df.name.str.len() == 4, 'value'] *= 1000
print (df)
          name   value
0         Alex  1000.0
1         John  2000.0
2  Christopher     3.0
3       Dwayne     4.0
```

EDIT:

More general solutions:

```
mask = df.name.str.len() == 4
df.loc[mask, 'value'] = df.loc[mask, 'value'] * 1000
```

Or:

```
df.update(df.loc[mask, 'value'] * 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @jezrael. However, if this was not a simple multiplication such as the second R case I exposed, how would it be?

Comment: Hmm, then is possible cache mask and use your solution with `loc` or use [`update`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.update.html)