# Set filtered rows of a column equal to the filtered rows of another column pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in pandas that looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'name' : pd.Series(['Alex', 'John', 'Christopher', 'Dwayne']),
                   'value' : pd.Series([1., 2., 3., 4.]),
                   'new_value' : pd.Series([np.NaN, 4, 5, 10])})

df
Out[1]: 
          name  value  new_value
0         Alex    1.0        NaN
1         John    2.0        4.0
2  Christopher    3.0        5.0
3       Dwayne    4.0       10.0
```

Now I want to update the value column, if the new value is not `NaN`. I did my SO searching and I found this answer: [Efficient way to update column value for subset of rows on Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766232/efficient-way-to-update-column-value-for-subset-of-rows-on-pandas-dataframe), which led me to the following (correct) construction:

```
df.loc[~df.new_value.isnull(), 'value'] = df.new_value
```

My question is, how does this work? Why is the right hand side of the assignment filtered as well by loc?

Comment: When you assign series by another series, the assignment works by index alignment.

Comment: Thank you! The reverse doesn't work though: `df['value'] = df.loc[~df.new_value.isnull(), 'new_value']`

Comment: Yes, it does, the missing index on the left-hand-side becomes `NaN`. Same if you do `df.loc[~df.new_value.isnull(), 'value'] = df.loc[some_other_condition, 'new_value']`

Comment: You are absolutely correct sir! My mistake I rushed into conclusions.

Comment: @QuangHoang would you care to post an answer to explain it a bit more for posterity purposes? (unless it has been answered somewhere before in which case happy to just close it)

Comment: @User2321, I've been using pandas lately but I had never officially read the full documentation. I'm doing it these days, and as it states in the beginning of the [Intro to data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/dsintro.html): "[...] **data alignment is intrinsic**. The link between labels and data will not be broken unless done so explicitly by you". So, by default, all operations among `DataFrame` and `Series` are performed in a index-aligned basis.

Answer (score 0):

`~df.new_value.isnull()` will provide the opposite of the data after the `~` with `True` `False` values (`True` becomes `False` and `False` becomes `True` ...).

Those values have indexes. So you are locating `df` by the indices that you just filtered (first argument) and you are making sure to choose only the values of `value`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"ali":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"mali":[4,2,6,4,5,6,10]})
df["kouki"] = df.loc[~(df.ali>3),"mali"]

# output
ali mali    kouki
0   1   4   4.0
1   2   2   2.0
2   3   6   6.0
3   4   4   NaN
4   5   5   NaN
5   6   6   NaN
6   7   10  NaN



df = pd.DataFrame({"ali":[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],"mali":[4,2,6,4,5,6,10]})
df["kouki"] = df.loc[(df.ali>3),"mali"]

# otuput
ali mali    kouki
0   1   4   NaN
1   2   2   NaN
2   3   6   NaN
3   4   4   4.0
4   5   5   5.0
5   6   6   6.0
6   7   10  10.0
```

Comment: Does that make any sense or is it heavily explained?

Comment: Well yes it does make sense but it doesn't answer my question :) I am not wondering about the left side but about the right side of the assignment.

Comment: The answer to my question is what @Quang Hoang  mentioned in the comments. Essentially what I could not understand is how the right hand side of the assignment gets filtered. I could not figure out the link between the indexes of the left side (filtered) and right hand side (which I thought was unfiltered)

Comment: @User2321 yes indeed, my bad i mis understood ur question. However, since we are filtering on the indexes of the `left hand side`, therefore, the only `affected` indexes are the ones `located` by the `left hand side` assignment and that answers your question i believe.

Comment: @User2321 right is just the column. So it follows what the left _says_