# Pandas updating a subset of rows multiple times leads to an unexpected result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe which requires multiple updates to one column using different subsets of rows per update. Each update corresponds to a set of rows which have a certain value for column A, where the B column should be given the values of the B column from another dataframe. A simple example is presented below, which works for the first update, but subsequent updates no longer change any of the values.

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2],
              'B': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1],
              'B': ["test1", "test2"]})
c = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2],
              'B': ["test3"]})

a.loc[a['A']==1, 'B'] = b['B']
a.loc[a['A']==2, 'B'] = c['B']

display(a)
```

The expected result would be {'A': [1, 1, 2], 'B': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']}

The actual result is {'A': [1, 1, 2], 'B': ['test1', 'test2', NaN]}

Related post that I have tried: [Efficient way to update column value for subset of rows on Pandas DataFrame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48766232/efficient-way-to-update-column-value-for-subset-of-rows-on-pandas-dataframe)

Performing some further testing, I found some unexpected behavior demonstrated by the following code

```
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2, 2],
                  'B': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1],
                  'B': ["test1", "test2"]})
c = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1],
                  'B': ["test3", "test4"]})

a.loc[a['A']==1, 'B'] = b['B']
a.loc[a['A']==2, 'B'] = c['B']

display(a)

a.loc[a['A']==2, 'B'] = ["test3", "test4"]

display(a)
```

which gives {'A': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B': ['test1', 'test2', NaN, NaN]} for the first display, and {'A': [1, 1, 2, 2], 'B': ['test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4']} for the second. The expected result was to have the same output twice.

Comment: You're dealing with index misalignment issues! Try assigning with `foo[...] = bar['B'].to_numpy()` instead, with `foo` and `bar` the corresponding Series or DataFrame

Comment: Here is more info: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html, in particular the first warning in the Basics section. This is also why assigning with a list directly works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the indexes don't align when you try and assign. That's why your final example, using a list does work as expected. You can use `.to_list()` or `.values` to make it work:

```py
a = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 2],
              'B': [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1],
              'B': ["test1", "test2"]})
c = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2],
              'B': ["test3"]})

a.loc[a['A']==1, 'B'] = b['B'].values
a.loc[a['A']==2, 'B'] = c['B'].values
```

Or alternatively set the index on dataframes b and c, but I'm not sure that will help with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thank you so much, that indeed fixed the issue for both the example case and the actual application. I would have never found out that that could have been the issue.